# Real time Code render mode in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

For a half year now, I carry an innovative idea for a modern way of code editing. I just realized what Visual Studio Code extensions are already capable of and made me wonder.

The idea is that **a real time code render mode for code editors** where code is **visualized like rendered documentation** (for example Doxygen). Non-commented lines of code are displayed like collapsable codeblocks and documentation comments are displayed as the surrounding markdown/HTML/LaTeX document.

This rendered view still **can be edited and navigated in same way as the classic text** view so that new graphical elements appear after typing them as text into a comment. Therefore, rich interactive **documentation reading** (like hiding/showing parts, jumping across locations with hyperlinks) **and code editing would be combined** into one activity without time needed for switching between both or mapping Documentation with actual code locations. Different from the original literate programming idea, the file's physical content is unchanged and doesn't complicate the process or source code reading.

It's **conceptually how Moodle** text editors work (HTML code view and render view) or like using a graphical word processor to visualize source code instead of a single monospace text. Of course, the cursor would move along lines in their visually presented order and not in their file's actual order.

Do you know, if such a real time render mode is **possible in VSCode**?
Did someone had such an idea and made an extension?

btw:
This "render mode" idea is actually quite generic and could be used as general customizable GUI technology that would allow GUI elements to be navigated, edited via an underlying text representation.

Comment: It's unintuitive to use merely words to describe complex concepts. If possible, you should draw prototype diagrams to illustrate what exactly you would like to achieve, and then analyze the VSCode API to see what parts can be utilized, https://code.visualstudio.com/api Keep in mind there are a lot of extensions out there showing the capabilities of such API, so you have tons to look around before saying possible or not.

Comment: Good point. That's possibly the reason why my unconventional ideas often are not received well. My current search found, IntelliJ has made a step towards that vision ( https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/03/intellij-idea-2020-1-eap8/ ) but I can't figure out whether this rendered view allows editing the source code base in real time. Javadoc is maybe too heavy. There is also an "outline editor" called Leo which apparently organizes multiple subfiles into a directed graph structure. The rendered result is presented based on Vue.js like a documentation/book. I don't know how useful it is.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting thing, but IMHO a lightweight editor like VSCode should focus on the core editing features (and documentation is rarely included). Besides, the editor is very much locked down with limited extensibility (intended and a good way to keep it clean and reliable), so requests like https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3220 have been pending for years. Alternatively, you can create a custom editor and show whatever you like (but it also has limitations).